# How can i get a SQL query only one per day?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database of phone communcations which send their location every 30s to 1m, i need to get a sumarry of their location history. as i have their communication every 30s, for only 3 days i have more than 500 results. how can i query to get only 1 result per day based on a hour?

```
SELECT id, version, to_char(datetime, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as data_camera,
       imei, to_char(inserted_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mm:ss') as data_sistema,
       latitude, longitude, speed AS VELOCIDADE
FROM heartbeat
WHERE imei = '5303023004057831' AND datetime BETWEEN '2021-05-03' AND '2021-06-08'
ORDER BY datetime;
```

I want to get only 1 result per day, or maybe get results based on a short time range, thank you!

Comment: Which day?  You have multiple date/time columns.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output data according to your requirement, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Which day? per day betweeb the datarange as written on the post!, the expected output is also written on the post

Comment: No, the question does not contain any **specific** data about the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one result per day, then use `DISTINCT ON`.  Assuming the "day" is based on `datetime`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (datetime::date) id, version,
       to_char(datetime, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') as data_camera,
       imei, to_char(inserted_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mm:ss') as data_sistema,
       latitude, longitude, speed AS VELOCIDADE
FROM heartbeat
WHERE imei = '5303023004057831' AND
      datetime BETWEEN '2021-05-03' AND '2021-06-08'
ORDER BY datetime::date;
```

This returns an arbitrary record each day.  You can determine which one by adjusting the `ORDER BY` with a second key.

Comment: Thanks!! is there i way i can filter by hour? anyway it worked well, thank you!

Comment: @Arthur . . . You can add a `where` clause to filter.